# How can I set existing EIPs to Auto scaled instances in AWS when they launch automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have cloud formation template which creates auto-scaling group with desired state 2. I need instances to be attached to existing eips when they get launched. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need EIP for Instances Launched in AS , are they(instances in ELB if you have) not in Private Subnet ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom user data script that assigns the elastic IP to the instance. You can not do this using CloudFormation templates yet. The AWS CLI to be used is: `aws ec2 associate-address`. For this, the best practice would be to assign and IAM role with `ec2:AssociateAddress` permission.

The command will look like this: `aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOCATION_ID --allow-reassociation`

While the allocation id will need to be hardcoded in the template, you can get the instance id within the instance using the command: `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`. Refer [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=498761)
 for more details.